# Jenkins Fail with: Host key verification failed

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I downloaded and installed Jenkins for Mac OSX on my Macbook Pro (OS: Mountain Lion). I now want to set it up to pull down a project from bitbucket and do an automatic build.

I created the ssh key, added it to bitbucket and tried to setup a build job. However, I get the error:

Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h  HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Host key verification failed. 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I tried to remove the domain causing the problem from known_hosts but am still getting this error.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found a possible solution in this post: http://colonelpanic.net/2011/06/jenkins-on-mac-os-x-git-w-ssh-public-key/

> Jenkins on Mac OS X I just finished setting up a build server on Mac
>   OS X using Jenkins (formerly Hudson). The company I’m working for
>   (GradeCam) uses git and gitolite for our source control and so I
>   expected no trouble using Jenkins to build our tools using the git
>   plugin.
>
> However, I quickly ran into a snag: the source control server is on a
>   public address and so our source code is not available except via ssh,
>   and gitolite ssh access uses private key authentication.  Well, I’m an
>   experience unix sysadmin, so that didn’t sound like a big issue —
>   after all, setting up public key authentication is childs play, right?
>
> Default install
>
> The default installation of Jenkins on Mac OS X (at the time of this
>   writing) installs a Launch Agent plist to
>   /Library/LaunchAgents/org.jenkins-ci.plist. This plist file causes
>   Jenkins to load as user “daemon”, which sounds fine — except that the
>   home directory for the “daemon” user is /var/root, same as for user
>   root.  This means that the .ssh dir in there will never have the right
>   permissions for a private key to be used.
>
> Creating a new hidden user
>
> My solution was to create a new “hidden” user for Jenkins to run
>   under. Following instructions I found on a blog post, I created a user
>   “jenkins” with a home directory “/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home”:
>
> ```
> sudo dscl . create /Users/jenkins
> sudo dscl . create /Users/jenkins PrimaryGroupID 1
> sudo dscl . create /Users/jenkins UniqueID 300   
> sudo dscl . create /Users/jenkins UserShell /bin/bash
> sudo dscl . passwd /Users/jenkins $PASSWORD
> sudo dscl . create /Users/jenkins home /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/
> ```
>
> I then stopped Jenkins:  `“sudo launchctl unload -w
>   /Library/LaunchAgents/org.jenkins-ci.plist”` and edited the plist file
>   to set the username to jenkins instead of daemon.
>
> ```
> “chown -R jenkins: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home”
> ```
>
> sets the permissions how they need to be, and then  `“sudo launchctl
>   load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.jenkins-ci.plist”` should get you up
>   and running!
>
> To get git over ssh running, “sudo su – jenkins” to get a console as
>   the jenkins user and set up the ssh keys and such. Make sure you can
>   ssh to where you want to go (or even do a test git clone) because you
>   need to save the keys so it doesn’t ask for them when jenkins tries to
>   do the clone.
>
> That should do you! Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Please make sure your answers do not depend on a URL. They need to last passed when the URL dies.